# Regular expressions for URI parsing

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I write little framework. Can't go to the url `/page/test`. Says `page not found`. Maybe something wrong with the regular expressions in the `urls.php`? It looks like the browser process the URL itself, however script should it does.

```
<?php

class griEngine {

public
    $settings, //settings
    $uri,  //current URI
    $app;  //curent app

public function __construct($settings) {

    $this->settings= $settings;
    $this->uri = urldecode(preg_replace('/\?.*/iu','',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
    $this->app = false;
    $this->process_path();
    $this->process_controllers();

}

public function process_path() {

    foreach( $this->settings['apps'] as $iterable_app )
    {
        $iterable_urls = require(BASE_DIR. '/apps/'. $iterable_app. '/urls.php');
        foreach( $iterable_urls as $pattern => $method)
        {
            $matches = array();
            if (preg_match($pattern, $this->uri, $matches))
            {

                $this->app = array($iterable_app, array('pattern' => $pattern, 'method' => $method, 'args' => $matches));
                break(2);


    }

    if( $this->app ==='false')
    {
        exit('App not found.');
    }
}

public function process_controllers() {

    if ($this->app || is_array($this->app))
    {
        require(BASE_DIR.'/apps/'.$this->app['0'].'/controller.php');
        $controller_name = $this->app['0'].'_Controller';
        $this->app_controller = new $controller_name();
        $this->app_controller->{$this->app['1']['method']}($this->app['1']['args']);
    } 
}


}
```

---

file urls.php

```
<?php

return array(

'#^/*$#i' => 'MainPage',
'#^/Page/([A-z0-9_-])/*#i' => 'ViewPage'

);
```

---

file controller.php

```
<?php


class Simple_Pages_Controller extends gri_Controller {

public function MainPage($args){
    echo 'Hello world';
}


public function ViewPage(){
    echo 'test';
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were missing `+` here `^/Page/([A-z0-9_-])/*#i`. As `test` in `/page/test` contains more than `1` character, so you should use `+`

**Change this to:**

```
return array(

'#^/*$#i' => 'MainPage',
'#^/Page/([A-z0-9_-])/*#i' => 'ViewPage'

);
```

**This:**

```
<?php
return array(

'#^/*$#i' => 'MainPage',
'#^/Page/([A-z0-9_-]+)/*#i' => 'ViewPage'

);
```

Comment: Thank you, but still "Object not found!" error 404 :(((

Comment: @Grigorie The problem with `regex` has been fixed now, Your current problem can be the problem of your `server`